# CMake target dependency in sub_directory header file not found

Tags: c++, cmake

**EDIT:** https://github.com/jasin/bytecoin-gui you can see the entire project here

I have tracked down the problem to the **CXX.includecache** file located in

```
{build_dir}/{sub_project}/src/CMakesFiles/CryptoNoteCore.dir/CXX.includecache
```

created by CMake. It contains this line

```
rocksdb/db.h
{build_dir}/{sub_project}/src/CryptoNoteCore/rocksdb/db.h
```

The above location is **WRONG** it should be

```
rocksdb/db.h
{build_dir}/{sub_project}/external/rocksdb/include/rocksdb/db.h
```

Now, I have setup my CMakelists directory structure as so

```
source_dir
--sub_project
  |--source
     |--CryptoNoteCore
  |--external
     |--rocksdb
--project_source
```

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt**, I add the **sub_directory** so I can generate the needed build files for my target dependencies.

```
add_subdirectory({sub_project})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${CRYPTONOTE_LIB}/external/rocksdb/include)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${BUILD_PLATFORM} ${SOURCES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS _GNU_SOURCE )
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
            include
            src
            ${CRYPTONOTE_LIB}/external/rocksdb/include
            ${CRYPTONOTE_LIB}/external
            ${CRYPTONOTE_LIB}/include
            ${CRYPTONOTE_LIB}/src/Platform/${PLATFORM_DIR}
            ${CRYPTONOTE_LIB}/src
            )
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
            ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
            ${QTMAIN}
            ${Qt5DBus_LIBRARIES}
            BlockchainExplorer
            Common
            Crypto
            CryptoNoteCore
            Http
            InProcessNode
            Logging
            NodeRpcProxy
            P2p
            Rpc
            Serialization
            System
            Transfers
            Wallet
            rocksdblib
            Qt5::Widgets
            Qt5::Gui
            Qt5::Network)
```

In the sub_project **CMakelists.txt** there is this line

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/rocksdb/include)
```

which should tell **CryptoNoteCore** where to find **rocksdb/db.h** But as stated at the top, the **CXX.includecache** file in picks up the wrong location. WHY???
As you can see, I tried to add in the correct include directory in **target_include_directories** and **include_directories** in hopes that CMake will see it, but something nefarious is going on here and I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**`{build_dir}/{sub_project}/src/CMakesFiles/CryptoNoteCore.dir/DependInfo.cmake`contains the correct include paths.

```
# The include file search paths:
set(CMAKE_CXX_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH
  "bytecoin/src"
  "D:/bytecoin-gui/bytecoin/src"
  "D:/boost_1_65_1"
  "D:/bytecoin-gui/bytecoin/include"
  "D:/bytecoin-gui/bytecoin/external"
  "bytecoin/version"
  "D:/bytecoin-gui/bytecoin/src/Platform/Windows"
  "D:/bytecoin-gui/bytecoin/src/platform/msc"
  "D:/bytecoin-gui/external/rocksdb/include"
  )
```

Comment: "the `CXX.includecache` file in picks up the wrong location." - Why the location `{build_dir}/{sub_project}/src/CryptoNoteCore/rocksdb/db.h` is **wrong**? It points to *non-existent* file? It uses include directory which you *never pass* to CMake? Or is it simply *unexpected* by you?

Comment: yes, seeing as that file doesn't even exist it is unexpected to see it being listed in the CXX.includecache file. As stated, CMake will never find that file, it is part of another project that I added as a sub_directory. Building the project by itself doesn't show the error, only when compiling it as a dependency to the project that added it as a sub_directory.

Comment: my goal here is to add this other project as a mere dependency, I do not wish to change anything about that project. It should compile exactly as is, but for some reason my actions of adding it as a sub_directory and then a dependency of my project it seems to confuse CMake on where that file should be located. The file exist right where the sub_project author meant to put it and it compiles fine using CMake on that projects CMakeLists.txt file outside of my project.

Comment: `It should compile exactly as is, but for some reason my actions of adding it as a sub_directory and then a dependency of my project it seems to confuse CMake on where that file should be located.` - Then it would be better to add 3d-party project as [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html). In that case, CMake will build the project as standalone, so it should definitely work. Adding 3d-party subproject with `add_subdirectory` is simpler sometimes, but not all projects can be added such way.

Comment: Well, I been working on a solution. I have found one, but it's not as I had hoped. The externalproject idea works, but I need to compile my project /MD and the external project is setup to compile in /MT. In fact it will not fully compile using /MD. So I need to edit the CMakeLists.txt in the externalproject and comment out the sub_directory(test) line and then all is OK. Got any advice on what is my best course of action with those results?

Comment: Check documentation about building your external project. Is is possible that it allows to change some configuration. Also, CMake support several options, which works for most projects, like setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.